# JavaScript grab text element and update to unordered list

Tags: javascript

I'm using Ruby on Rails to generate an array of data that's displaying a row with index and an error. Unfortunately I can't grab the flash notice to iterate over as it's in the CMS. Apparently trying to do a join with a break doesn't seem to work. And since straight up CSS isn't possible on a text element.

How can I grab a text element and then create an unordered list?

The HTML ends up looking like:

```
<div class="alert-error">
 <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</a>
 "  Row 2: Email can't be blank 
  Row 5: First Name can't be blank 
  Row 9: Email invalid due to being an incorrect email, Last Name required, City is required"
</div>
```

This display however shows: 
Row 2: Email can't be blank Row 5: First Name can't be blank Row 9: Email invalid due to being an incorrect email, Last Name required, City is required

I am a relative novice when it comes to JavaScript and I played around with doing a variable on the class itself. But how do I get the text itself and then separate? I could add in a period between the elements but then I would need to find the text element then being able to separate by the period and then create an unordered list. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [innerText](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp) property on your element, in order to get the contents of this div.

Once you have your string, you can use [split("\n")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on your string, in order to create an array from your string.

Comment: This fails but I like the direction. So right now I'm doing var els = document.getElementsByClassName('alert-error').innerText; will show undefined in console. If I do els.split("\n") I'll get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: getElementsByClassName() returns an array, because multiple elements can have the same class. Try appending `[0]` like this: `document.getElementsByClassName('alert-error')[0].innerText`

Comment: Ahh got it. Would actually need to put it to [1] with the link but that's goood.